# Convert EDI to multiple XMLs using smooks

Tags: java, xml, edi, smooks

I am new to smooks. Through the examples given in smooks github, I am able to convert an EDI to XML successfully. But the problem is that the size of generated XML is too huge. For example one MB edi is generating 16 MB XML.

So I was thinking to split one EDI to multiple XML based on transaction sets i.e., One XML per transaction set

Is there a way to generate multiple XML from a single EDI file using Smooks?

Answer (score 0):

Smooks is generating a stream of Sax events. The fact that that stream was from an Edi source is irrelevant. So, if you look at one of the splitting examples, you should be able to use the same approach.